# Excel VBA: How to change order of scenarios

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run VBA loop on excel defined scenarios ("What-if-analysis") and I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to change the order of scenarios in "scenario manager" itself. I couldn't find a way.
2. Is it possible to run the for loop only on subset of the scenarios?
   currently I use this code for the loop:
   "For Each sc In Sheets("Casimir_power").Scenarios"
   which runs over all the existing scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

1. The order is based on when the scenario was created. So yes you can, but you'd have to delete your prior entries. You could probably write a macro to do it if you were really motivated.
2. The best option would be to continue to loop through all your scenarios but create a condition that determines whether or not to execute your procedure. It's probably easiest to just check if the `name` of the scenario matches what you want. See the example below that will run code if `Scenario` matches one of two names. You could also base it on the range of the scenario, or anything else that's in the [Scenario Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.scenarios).

   Sub eachScenario()
   Dim s As Scenario, ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Sheets("Casimir_power")

   ```
    For Each s In ws.Scenarios
        Debug.Print s.Name
        If s.Name = "?????" Or s.Name = "!!!!!" Then
            s.Show 'or whatever
        Else
            'skip
        End If
    Next s
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: Thanks for your response! Regarding #1 - I'm not sure what does it mean to delete prior entries? I have many scenarios arranged by groups which I ran macro on. if I'll need to add scenario which belongs to the first group, I'd like the option to add it in the first scenarios and not last. Is it possible?

Comment: It means to delete existing scenarios.  I'm not too famaliar with sub groups of scenarios, but I'm certain the above code will allows you to limit your macro. If that works, i'd be most grateful if you click `accept`. Thanks.